# javascript and css links not working on sever

Tags: functions, javascript, links

I have some Jquery links in my header. First off I am probably not using the proper wordpress function to do this. Right now on my site the code that is below is not working. These links aren't there, but in my ftp directory they exist. I am not sure what I am doing wrong? I can link to the live site if needed.

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://fiftyfity.com/wp-content/themes/fiftyfityNew/jQuery-ui-1/css/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel=stylesheet />
<script src="http://fiftyfity.com/wp-content/themes/fiftyfityNew/jQuery-ui-1/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://fiftyfity.com/wp-content/themes/fiftyfityNew/jQuery-ui-1/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
```

and here is the code before output

```
 <?php $url = content_url();?>
<link type="text/css" href="<?php echo $url; ?>/themes/fiftyfityNew/jQuery-ui-1/css/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script src="<?php echo $url; ?>/themes/fiftyfityNew/jQuery-ui-1/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $url; ?>/themes/fiftyfityNew/jQuery-ui-1/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When I go to http://fiftyfity.com/wp-content/themes/fiftyfityNew/jQuery-ui-1/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js I get an http auth prompt. If that's the real address and not FPO, I'm guessing that's your issue. Those files will need to be publicly accessible

Comment: How would I go about keeping my site private while I test it. I was just using .htaccess I didn't think that should make the links not work.

Comment: There are [a number of plugins to do this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/password-protect), which is almost certainly the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to include styles and scripts is with the `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` functions. The codex pages on both of these functions covers how to use them very well. Basically you just need to give the script the source (do it relative to your current PHP file) of the script/style and a slug to reference it by. If you're enqueueing conditionally, then you should look at `wp_register_script()` and `wp_register_style()` as well.

Comment: I will try this. My wordpress just started acting up with something else, so I am reinstalling.

Comment: I really couldn't figure this out, could you explain a little bit.

Comment: What part of it is confusing you? If it's complicated, it may be served with a better question...I know implementation of the `enqueues` has been hashed and rehashed dozens of times on this site, have you tried looking at any of those?